# On three.js Replacing a meterial with MeshPhysicalMaterial with normalMap is not working

Tags: three.js

I am loading a GLTF model.  I then need to replace the material of some of the meshes with a MeshPhysicalMaterial (MPM). This MPM material has a normalMap from a texture that I previously loaded. When replacing the material all the meshes with the new material are just black. If I replace the material but not add the normalMap it works OK.

If I add the MPM material on a new object it also works as expected. I guess I need to mark something as needing update but I am not sure what.

I have tried the following:

```
    material.vertexColors = parseInt(material.vertexColors); //Ensure number
    material.side = parseInt(material.side); //Ensure number
    material.needsUpdate = true;
    geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;
    geometry.attributes.normal.needsUpdate = true;
    if (geometry.attributes.color) {
      geometry.attributes.color.needsUpdate = true;
    }
    geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
    geometry.elementsNeedUpdate = true;
    geometry.morphTargetsNeedUpdate = true;
    geometry.uvsNeedUpdate = true;
    geometry.normalsNeedUpdate = true;
    geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true;
    geometry.tangentsNeedUpdate = true;
```

But nothing seems to work. Any ideas would be very much appreciated.

Comment: As mentioned in the [documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#examples/en/loaders/GLTFLoader), textures of a `glTF` asset require their `flipY` property set to `false`. The loader automatically does this for you. However, if you manually define a texture after the loading process, you also have to configure this property correctly. Can you please do this and see what happens?

Comment: Good tip, but no, unfortunately it didn't help.

Comment: Any way you can post a working example of this problem? It could be so many things, it's difficult to tell from the code you've posted above.

Comment: My latest working theory is that the model itself doesn't have the UV Mapping set correctly, if at all. Unfortunately I am not able to post this particular model for NDA reasons. Will give feedback here if this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

On r.160 I was having trouble displaying a loaded normalMap until I did the following after loading the normalMap.

1. I had a wrapping texture applied as a map, so I had to use the same wrapping settings for the loaded normalMap, i.e.

```
normalMap.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
normalMap.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
normalMap.repeat.set(0.2, 0.2);
material.normalMap = normalMap;
```

2. I also had to change the normalMapType: `material.normalMapType = THREE.ObjectSpaceNormalMap;`

I don't know if this applies to your situation but it helped me.